# how to go from one fragment to previously opened fragment using back stack

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

For example I want to go back to home before exiting my app.

This is my code....

case 0:
      frag = new Home();

case 1:
     frag = new AboutUs();

```
transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.fragemnt_container, frag);
transaction.commit();
```

If i click on Home button in navigation drawer and then click on aboutus button, and When i press back button on my phone i want to go from aboutus fragment to home fragment without exiting my app.

Any Help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `FragmentTransaction` to the backstack. It is as simple as calling `addToBackStack()` before you commit the transaction.